# Windows XP: is DVD drive connected to master or slave on the IDE port?

Tags: windows-xp, optical-drive, pata

I'm running a German Windows XP Professional and want to know whether my IDE-DVD-drive is connected to the master or slave without opening the machine. The device manager shows *Ort: Pfad 0 (0)* (in English: *Location: path 0 (0)*?) on the first properties page of the DVD drive below the *Hersteller* (in English: *Vendor*?). Does this mean it is the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's on the master.  it's on channel 0, device 0.  Slave is generally device 1.

Comment: mostly correct.  if you have it manually set to master by jumper instead of cable select, this might not be accurate

Answer (score 1):

Download the Nero Info tool

http://www.nero.com/enu/support-nero8-tools-utilities.html

Run it and then go to the Configuration tab.